# Why does Thor burn an imprint when he flies?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

**This is NOT a duplicate because this question does not mention the bifrost while the other question does. The two questions have very different levels of abstraction and are thus very different from each other.**

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Thor leaves at the end by flying up into the sky and leaving an imprint burned into the ground. Stark comments that Thor has no regard for lawn maintenance.

I noticed other times when Thor flies without burning a mark in the ground.

**Why does Thor burn a mark in the ground during some flights but not during other flights?**  If the answer is that he only burns when he is going off world, then what specifically is causing the burning? How does the mechanism work?

Comment: @CodeMed this question doesn't mention the Bifrost but it should because that's what Thor used at the end of the movie...

Comment: ***then what specifically is causing the burning? How does the mechanism work?*** yes, it is a duplicate.

Comment: The issue here is two-fold. 1) The premise is incorrect to begin with. The burn patterns have nothing to do with Thor flying. 2) Once you ignore the incorrect assumption that Thor/Mjolnir are creating the patterns, the other question and the answers to it discuss the fact that the burn patterns are created by the Bifrost. The questions you specifically asked are pretty well covered.

Answer (score 9):

The complex burn marks left in the ground are not caused by Thor flying - they are scorch marks left over from the Bifrost, which is used to travel inbetween the nine realms and is located in Asgard.

The Bifrost first appears in *Thor*, before later appearing in *Thor: The Dark World*. The same marks as the ones seen at the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* can be seen in *Thor: The Dark World* when Thor takes Jane from London to Asgard using the Bifrost.

[image: Bifrost scorch marks in London, with bonus Darcy]

As for the burn marks themselves - we see in *Thor* that when left unchecked, the Bifrost can destroy entire realms, something which begins to happen when Loki leaves it open and pointing at Jotunheim, the home of the Frost Giants. As such, we can assume that it outputs huge amounts of energy in order to transport people from one realm to another, and as such scorches the ground when it does so.

Comment: That man is a menace to gardeners

Comment: @Petersaber - This guy has no regard for lawn maintenance :P

Comment: Idk, looks like job security for them